# Renaming rails route parameter to id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In my `routes.rb` file, I have the following resources

```rb
resources :classrooms, only: [:index, :new, :create] do
  resources :students, only: [:index, :edit, :update], controller: 'students' do
    get :honor
  end
end
```

My honor route becomes `/classrooms/:classroom_id/students/:students_id/honor(.:format)`
but I want to replace `student_id` to `id` so that I can easily use it in the students controllers.

Ideal route is `/classrooms/:classroom_id/students/:id/honor(.:format)`

Comment: BTW, you don't need `controller: 'students'` here

Comment: Advice: check if you really need nested resources. Maybe a student can attend different classrooms. Also, as silver lining you'll get the params :id  as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that specifying it's a member route. this way

```
get :honor, on: :member
```

or

```
member do
  get :honor
end
```